# CSS: having scrollbar always visible without reducing width of the container

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to have an always visible scrollbar in a vertically scrollable div, but without having the scrollbar reducing the width of the elements inside the div. 
Basically I would like to have the default behaviour of the browsers with a div using "overflow-y: scroll", but without having the scrollbar disappearing when not scrolling.

I've tried the following but as you can see the scrollbar reduces the available width of the div, which I don't want.

Is this possible?

```css
/* Css Reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------ */

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 2em;
}

#content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 12em;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    height: 4px;
    width: 0.5em;
    background: transparent;
}

#content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: green;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

#content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  background: #333; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>scrollbar</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=yes" />
    
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <li class="item">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want to have scroll bar or not? because auto hide generally will happen in mac system. windows will be visible always.

Comment: You want a scrollbar that's always present but it should not decrease the size of te container it is on. In that case you can have overflow-y: scroll on the element and give the element extra padding to the right to accommodate for the width of the scrollbar (I think most browsers it is around 17px).

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want it to work with with the webkit psuedo class then you will need to do it this way

```css
.scrollbar {
 margin-left: 22px;
 float: left;
 height: 180px;
 width: 200px;
 background: #F5F5F5;
 overflow-y: scroll;
  margin:10px;
}
.force-overflow {
 min-height: 450px;
}
#wrapper {
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
}
#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 20px;
}

/**  STYLE A */
#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: green;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbar" id="style-1">
    <div class="force-overflow"><h2>A</h2></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbar" id="style-default">
    <div class="force-overflow"><h2>B</h2></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice am just doing this `-webkit-scrollbar`